# ServiceStack credentials auth endpoint gives 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, servicestack

I am running a ServiceStack app on IIS 7.5, with a custom CredentialsAuthProvider serving at `/auth/credentials`.

It works fine from Visual Studio, but when I install it on the production server (also IIS 7.5), it responds 404 to all requests to `/auth/credentials`. It doesn't have any trouble serving REST endpoints, and authentication works if I change the provider's superclass to BasicAuthProvider, but I would like to use forms instead of basic auth. How can I get it to serve the auth endpoint correctly?

This is what my Web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
  <location path="auth">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="rest">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

  <!-- Required for MONO -->
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="rest*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
      <add path="auth*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
            <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://nearme.solarcity.com" responseMode="Redirect" />
        </httpErrors>
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>-->
    <!--uncomment this to stop IIS 7.5 from blocking PUT and DELETE-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making the wrong assumptions in your configuration.

You can only host ServiceStack at **one single path** which is either at the root path `*` or at a custom path which is generally by convention either `/api` or `/servicestack` but can be any name of your choice. The HelloWorld tutorial [shows an example configuration for both supported options](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#rootpath).

Authentication is enforced by decorating either the Request DTO or Service with an [Authenticate] attribute. If you wish you can also add the attribute to a custom base class, e.g. `AuthenticatedServiceBase` which will ensure all sub classes require authentication as well.

Comment: +1, try using MonoDevelop instead of Visual Studio when building ServiceStack apps. It doesn't hide stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks! I set ServiceStack to host from the root path, adjusted some endpoints, and everything works now.